# Access to Service Fabric Explorer without client certificate

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to connect to Service Fabric Explorer using only Azure AD account without client certificate installed locally?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @4c74356b41 How to configure it? In all manuals I see only examples with client certificate.

Comment: web interface supports that

Comment: @4c74356b41 I created test SF cluster, added myself as an `Owner`. But I see `You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403` when I open SFX. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i dont have a way to test right now, but you'd have to add yourself to the admin AAD group on SF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-setup-aad

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thank you for the link, I'll try it. Do I still need certificate installed locally to connect to a cluster through `sfctl` util from my machine?

Comment: probably yes, but sfx is available like any other website